# jQuery - delay after addClass in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class `editing` to my links but with a nice animation, so I need the each class to be added after slight delay.

How can I achieve this?
I tried with inserting and empty `setTimeout` inside the loop but it didn't work.

```
var $links = $('.my_box .link');
$link.each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('editing');
    // A delay should be here
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```js
function markLinks() {
  var $links = $('.my_box .link');
  $links.each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.delay(i * 200).queue(function() {
      $this.toggleClass("editing").dequeue();
    });
  });
  setTimeout(markLinks, 1500);
}
markLinks();
```

```css
.editing {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_box">
  <div class="link">one</div>
  <div class="link">two</div>
  <div class="link">three</div>
  <div class="link">four</div>
  <div class="link">five</div>
  <div class="link">six</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`delay` sets a delay in the animation queue, and `queue` schedules a function call on that queue. Note that you need to [`dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) in the `queue` callback, since the nature of animation is that that callback might be starting something that it finishes later (but in your case, you aren't).

Comment: This is amazing. I was trying to do something similar to this but I didn't know about the queue function and that is why it didn't work! Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to dequeue something after I use it? 
I want to be able also to remove the same class after clicking a button, and after first click this works like magic, but after I click it second time (this time I change addClass to removeClass) nothing happens

Comment: @Ancinek: Yes, sorry about that; fixed above.